# Get a particular instance of a class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, relation

I have created a model for UnitOfMeasure (UOM) and a model for ingredient where I would like to use UOM to enter a default UOM for the ingredient.

```
 public class IngredientModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public UnitOfMeasureModel DefaultUOM { get; set; }
    }

 public class UnitOfMeasureModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Abbreviation { get; set; }
    }
```

I would like to use the Name property in the IngredientModel.

In configure.cs I have put this code to create some default data for the database:

```
    protected override void Seed(RecipeApplication.Models.RecipeApplicationDb context)
    {
        if (!context.UnitOfMeasures.Any())
        {
            context.UnitOfMeasures.AddOrUpdate(
                u => u.Id,
                new UnitOfMeasureModel { Name = "Gram", Abbreviation = "g" },
                new UnitOfMeasureModel { Name = "Kilogram", Abbreviation = "kg"},
                new UnitOfMeasureModel { Name = "Milligram", Abbreviation = "mg" }
                );
        }

        if (!context.Ingredients.Any())
        {
            context.Ingredients.AddOrUpdate(
                i => i.Id,
                new IngredientModel { Name = "Italiaanse Ham", DefaultUOM = 
                );
        }

    }
```

I did not enter anything yet at default UOM because that is where I got stuck.

Could someone help me with this issue?

Comment: @CodeCaster I have to create new instances so I can use them in multiple classes. Else I would have to do this for every item I would like to create.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you just want to be able to access one of the UnitOfMeasureModel classes in both the UnitOfMeasures.AddOrUpdate and the UnitOfMeasures.AddOrUpdate methods. To do this create the instance before the calls and use that same instance in each AddOrUpdate method like so.....

```
protected override void Seed(RecipeApplication.Models.RecipeApplicationDb context)
{
    var defaultUOM = new UnitOfMeasureModel { Name = "Gram", Abbreviation = "g" };

    if (!context.UnitOfMeasures.Any())
    {
        context.UnitOfMeasures.AddOrUpdate(
            u => u.Id,
            defaultUOM,
            new UnitOfMeasureModel { Name = "Kilogram", Abbreviation = "kg"},
            new UnitOfMeasureModel { Name = "Milligram", Abbreviation = "mg" }
            );
    }

    if (!context.Ingredients.Any())
    {
        context.Ingredients.AddOrUpdate(
            i => i.Id,
            new IngredientModel { Name = "Italiaanse Ham", DefaultUOM = defaultUOM
            );
    }

}
```

obviously you can change if gram is not the correct default